# Socket.io server don't receive my signal

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

My app is an app message. I emit a 'send message' from the client and I want the server to do stuff on.

Here is my code:

**Client** (actualy working since i have the console.log in my console)

```
$('.send').click( () => {
    const message = $('#message').val()
    socket.emit('send message', {from: "Maxime", message: message});
    console.log('Message Send: Maxime - ${message}');
})
```

**Server** (Express - app.js)

```
io.on('send message', (from, message) => {
    console.log('bip!');
    console.log('Message send from ${from} saying ${message}');
})
```

(backtide are in the real code.)

I don't see any logs in my server console.

I want my server to response as expected.

Thanks you.

Comment: There are lots of possible pitfalls here, for one the client has to connect to the server first, but you haven't provided the respective server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters in the function where you receive socket messages are incorrect. There should be just one parameter *data* that is a json object, and it has the actual message from the socket in that *data* variable.

Your code should look like this:

```
  io.on('send message', (data) =>{ 
     console.log('bip!');
     console.log('Message send from '+data.from+' saying '+data.message); 
    })
```

Also, you should avoid using spaces in your socket messages name. For example, use *message* instead of *send message* (make sure to replace *send message* with *message* in both your server and client JavaScript.